# Find separates filenames when they contain a space (Shell)

Tags: bash, shell

So, my program is meant to cycle through a directory and its subdirectories, and when it finds a file that is larger than 100K, asks the user if they want to remove it.

I am using find to cycle through the directories. This is my code:

```
for file in $(find /home/* -print0 | xargs -0)
```

I have also tried

```
for file in $(find /home/* -exec process)
```

Etc, etc. Pretty much everything on the first five pages of Google.

Just to re-iterate, the problem is that find separates filenames with spaces in them. (i.e. "/home/Old data" would become "/home/Old" and "data"

Anyway, are there any better alternatives that I could be using?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Why is this tagged “vim”?

Comment: Why is the tagged "ubuntu"?

Comment: The problem is in the title -- It separates files with spaces in them

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop to prevent word splitting:

```
while read -r file; do
  # do something here
  echo "${file}"     # Remember to quote the variable
done < <(find /path -type f -size +200)
```

Comment: It seems as though this just prints every filename together without doing what is contained in the while loop

Comment: @user3280527 There was a typo; it should have actually thrown an error.  Moreover, if you ask `find` to produce null-terminated output and pipe it to `xargs` as your question, you'd see exactly what you've described/

Comment: Oh-- I think I should also mention that I'm running the script as sh, so that causes a bit of issue.
When I run your solution as bash, it does work

Comment: @user3280527 The `<(...)` syntax is referred to as Process Substitution which isn't available in `sh`.

Comment: @user3280527 in sh, you can use `find .. | while read ..`. Just beware that this may create a subshell, so variables set in the loop may not be available afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the shell, not with `find`. devnull has suggested a general fix, but for your specific problem, you can do:

```
find /path -type f -size +100k -exec ls -lh {} \; -exec rm -i {} \;
```

For files over 100k, this will list its attributes and ask the user whether to delete.

Answer (score 1):

The process substitution `$(...)` isn't quoted, so all the filenames come out on one line, separated by spaces. There's no way then to tell which spaces are in filenames and which are separators. But if you quote it, `"$(...)"`, then all the output comes out as a single multi-line string. So doing it this way, passing the command output to a `for` loop, doesn't work. Instead, use the `xargs` to do the work.

```sh
find /home/* -print0 | xargs -0 -i{} ls -l {}
```

This works exactly like your `find|xargs` except that the `xargs` is given a command to execute. In your case it will be a shell script in a file, e.g. `mayberemove.sh`. Normally `xargs` appends as many input lines onto the end of the command as it can, but the `-i` tells it to run the command with the input line in place of the (arbitrary) string `{}`. In this case it only uses one input line at a time. Because `xargs` isn't passing the argument through a shell, but instead runs the command using some variety of `exec`, there's no need for any more quoting. The `-0` means that the arguments are delimited by a null byte, as output by `find -print0`, to avoid problems with whitespace.

Instead of `ls -l`, you will want something like:

```sh
find /home/* -print0 | xargs -0 -i{} ./mayberemove.sh
```

where `mayberemove.sh` is careful to quote its arguments, because it *is* passing them using the shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

if ....
then
    rm "$1"
fi
```