# Error from wc -w $(find ...) only on some directories

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a line in bash to count all the words in all the text files on my PC which goes like this:

`wc -w $(find -type f -name "*.txt")`

It seems to be working good when I use it on a smaller parts of disk, for example Desktop, but when I try to use find on HOME or even Documents, it fails with a strange error:

`wc: invalid option -- 'F'`

When only the part for finding files is used (`find -type f -name "*.txt"`), there are no errors, it prints all text files as expected.

What could be the problem?

Comment: try `find -type f -name "*.txt" -exec wc -w +`

Comment: `find: missing argument to `-exec'` ...

Comment: That error is what you get if you have a filename with spaces that, followed by a dash, followed by an `F`. Don't ever use `$(find ...)`; it relies on word-splitting to split the output into names, which is inherently unreliable. (See [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) for more on that error).

Comment: ...the issue you hit is a different manifestation of the one discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336884/cant-take-file-names-with-spaces-in-shell-script-for-loop and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608923/find-separates-filenames-when-they-contain-a-space-shell, the only real difference being that you have a name (after being split on spaces) has a component that starts with a dash causing a fairly-unique error.

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have `find` itself put the files on `wc`'s command line:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec wc -w -- {} +
```

...or, if your `find` is too old to support `-exec ... {} +`, you can use `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 wc -w --
```